# SQLite is inserting data entry twice

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am having an issue where the item is getting inserted to my db twice. I dont have 2 insert statements.

I am trying to check if an array's element is empty.

Here are snippets of my code

In my main activity

```
private String[] dateTimeDispStr= new String[2];
```

in onCreate:

```
dateTimeDispStr[0]=null;
dateTimeDispStr[1]=null;
```

Other parts of same activity:

```
//-------------------------------------------update time----------------------------------------//    
public void updatetime()
{
    dateTimeDispStr[0]=new StringBuilder()
    .append(pad(mhour)).append(":")
    .append(pad(mminute)).toString();

    tdv.editRow(this, dateTimeDispStr);
    if(dateTimeDispStr[1]!=null){
        update();
    }

}

//-------------------------------------------update date----------------------------------------//    
private void updateDate() {
    dateTimeDispStr[1]=new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based so add 1
    .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
    .append(mDay).append("/")
    .append(mYear).append(" ").toString();

    tdv.editRow(this, dateTimeDispStr);
    if(dateTimeDispStr[0]!=null){
        update();
    }

}


SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM");

public void update(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(mYear, mMonth + 1, mDay, mhour, mminute, 0);
    String date = formatter.format(cal.getTime());

    tdi.setDate(date.split(" ")); // split makes an array of ["date", "time"]
    db.addItem(tdi);
    Log.d("Item set in the db", "The item: " + date);
}
```

Here is my database handler

```
// Adding new ToDoItem
public void addItem(ToDoItem item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TASK, item.getTDItem()); // item task
        values.put(KEY_DATE, item.getDate()); // item date
        values.put(KEY_PRIORITY, item.getPriority()); // item priority

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_TDL, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

tdv.editRow edits the row on my UI that is extending a table layout. I will add the functionality for checking for null in a sec. It essentially appends the row that already had the task of the todo item, but with date and time I would like to add them to that row

I understand that I call update in both methods, but that is because if the user clicks either button first.

Comment: Why dont you use db.update() if you want to update...

Comment: Do you ever reset `dateTimeDispStr`? Otherwise the data will be inserted twice after the first insert.

Comment: basically i want to add a new entry when I have both the time and date for my item

Comment: Actually I have not reset, but it adds twice the first time I add an item

Comment: How do you define and initialize `dateTimeDispStr`?

Comment: note that if both date and time are NOT empty, `update()` will be called twice, and it will append new entry twice

Comment: @Sam, String [2]..
mvp, I check if they are not empty

Comment: What I do is that I have button press for the time and date dialogs to pop up, and updatetime or updatedate puts their value in a String array of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all that I would simply fetch a Calendar instance, populate it with your date / time variables, and use a DateFormat to build a localized String.

Try this `update()` by itself:

```
// Create a field variable
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"); // HH for 24hr

public void update(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(mYear, mMonth + 1, mDay, mhour, mminute, 0);
    String date = formatter.format(cal.getTime());

    tdi.setDate(date.split(" ")); // split makes an array of ["date", "time"]
    db.addItem(tdi);
    Log.d("Item set in the db", "The item: " + date);
}
```

(I don't have a working compiler at the moment so forgive any minor flaws...)
Read about customizing the SimpleDateFormat string [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: when i change the date and time, my display for that field SHOULD BE <TIME DATE>
where when one button is pressed, is <TIME null> then when the other is pressed is <null DATE> 


edit: my bad, I initially make them "" need to first make them null.

Comment: as well as 2 entries for the db, one with the time and no date, and the second one with both

Comment: Please update your question with your current code. Also what does `tdv.editRow()` do and do you reference `dateTimeDispStr` anywhere else?

Comment: edited, I do not use dateTimeDispStr anywhere else, just that I only initialize it in onCreate

Comment: I proposed a simpler, more standard approach. With this you don't need the other methods please give it a try. (I think pass the data to `setDate()` in the wrong order but that's an easy fix.)

Comment: Alright, so that kinda fixed my display issue... but now is adding the entry twice to the db

Comment: I do have it called twice, but I would like to make sure that I can get it from either method in case the user enters the date first rather than the time

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22684/discussion-between-vnge-and-sam)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't have 2 insert statements but you're calling the **addItem()** method twice.

lets say you need to update the date and the time.. from your code
when you're updating the time.. you call the **update()** method which calls the **addItem()** method that insert the item to DB. next, when you're updating the date of the same item, you call the **update()** again
which calls the **addItem()** method that insert the item once again to the DB.

Hope this was helpful